# Не работают Breakpointы в slick

Tags: css, slider-slick.js, breakpoint

проблема в том что breakpoint не срабатывает ставлю на 992 проверяю слайдеру вообще побоку! подскажите что не так?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.carousel__inner').slick({
        centerPadding: '100px',
        infinite: true,
        speed: 300,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        centerMode: true,
        variableWidth: true,
        prevArrow: '<button type="button" class="slick-prev"><img src="../src/img/left.png" alt=""></button>',
        nextArrow: '<button type="button" class="slick-next"><img src="../src/img/right.png" alt=""></button>',

        responsive: [
          {
            breakpoint: 993,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: 3,
              slidesToScroll: 1,
              infinite: true,
              speed: 300,
              variableWidth: true
            }
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 600,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: 2,
              slidesToScroll: 1
            }
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 480,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: 1,
              slidesToScroll: 1
            }
          }
        ]
      });
  });
```

```css
@import 'adaptive/media';

*{
    font-family: RF Rufo;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.container {
    width: 1300px;
}
header {
    padding: 30px 30px 101px 0px;
    background-color: #000;
    height: 100%;
}
.header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    &_nav {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
    }
    &_menu {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        list-style-type: none;
        font-family: RF Rufo;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 15px;
        line-height: 134.3%;
        letter-spacing: 0.13em;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        a {
            &::after {
                position: absolute;
                content: '';
                display: block;
                width: 0px;
                height: 0px;
                background-color: red;
                margin-top: 7px;
                
            }
            &:hover {
    
                &::after {
                    position: absolute;
                    content: '';
                    display: block;
                    width: 61px;
                    height: 3px;
                    background-color: red;
                    transition: 0.5s all;
                    margin-top: 7px;
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
    &_shopping {
        font-family: RF Rufo;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 22px;
        line-height: 134.3%;
        letter-spacing: 0.13em;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        &_icon {
            margin-right: 31px;
        }
    }
    a {
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
}
.promo {
    padding-top: 36px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 100px;

    &_header {
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 100;
        font-size: 72px;
        line-height: 103.5%;
        letter-spacing: 0.025em;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    &_wrapper {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 545px;
        color: white;
    }
    &_subheader {
        margin-top: 49px;
        font-family: Montserrat;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 165%;
        color: #A8A8AA;
    }
    &_block {
        margin-left: 100px;
        &_item {
            align-items: center;
            display: inline-block;
            height: 250px;
            width: 250px;
            position: relative;
            margin-right: 20px;
            
            .title {
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: normal;
                font-size: 30px;
                line-height: 103.5%;
                letter-spacing: 0.025em;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                color: white;
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 94px;
                padding: 0 22px;
            }
            .text_block {
                font-family: Montserrat;
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 500;
                font-size: 14px;
                line-height: 154.4%;
                color: white;
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 17px;
                padding: 0 22px;
                
            }
        }

    }
    &_item_1 {
        background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0,00, 0.6)), url(../img/coffe.png) center center/cover no-repeat ;
        margin-right: 20px;
        &:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
            background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(251, 79, 80, 0.7), rgba(251, 79, 80, 0.7)), url(../img/coffe.png) center center/cover no-repeat ;
        }
    }
    &_item_2 {
        background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0,00, 0.6)), url(../img/machine.png) center center/cover no-repeat ;
        &:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
            background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(251, 79, 80, 0.7), rgba(251, 79, 80, 0.7)), url(../img/machine.png) center center/cover no-repeat ;
        }
    }
    &_item_3 {
        background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0,00, 0.6)), url(../img/milk.png) center center/cover no-repeat ;
        opacity: .2;
    }
    &_item_4 {
        background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0,00, 0.6)), url(../img/barista.png) center center/cover no-repeat ;
        opacity: .2;
    }
    &_item_5 {
        background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0,00, 0.6)), url(../img/woman.png) center center/cover no-repeat ;
        opacity: .2;
    }
    &_item_6 {
        background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0,00, 0.6)), url(../img/building.png) center center/cover no-repeat ;
        opacity: .2;
    }
    &_item_7 {
        background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0,00, 0.6)), url(../img/company.png) center center/cover no-repeat ;
        opacity: .2;
    }
    &_item_8 {
        background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0,00, 0.6)), url(../img/milk.png) center center/cover no-repeat ;
        opacity: .2;
    }
}
.carousel{
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    // width: 1400px;
    &__inner {
        position: relative;
        // width: 120%;
        // right: 320px;

    
    }
    .slick-prev{
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-70%);
        left: 290px;
        z-index: 1;
        background: none;
        border: none;
       img {
           width: 21px;
           height: 50px;
       }
    }
    .slick-next {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-70%);
        right: 300px;
        z-index: 1;
        background: none;
        border: none;
    }
    .slick-active  {
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    }
}
.hamburger {
    display: none;
    z-index: 1;
    background: none;
    width: 23px;
    height: 16px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    right: 18px;
    position: fixed;
    align-items: flex-end;
    top: 30px;
    display: none;
}
.line_1 {
    width: 23px;
    height: 2px;
    background: white;
    display: inline-block;
    
}
.line_2 {
    width: 19px;
    height: 2px;
    background: white;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.line_3 {
    width: 16px;
    height: 2px;
    background: white;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.phone_icon {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 18px;
    top: 30px;
    display: none;
    img {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
.item_dis_no {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-grid.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slick.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/fonts.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
       <div class="container">
            <div class="header">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <nav class="header_nav">
                        <img class="logo" src="img/Group.png" alt="">
                        <ul class="header_menu col-md-5 offset-md-1">
                            <li class="menu_item"><a href="#">Продажа</a></li>
                            <li class="menu_item"><a href="#">Аренда</a></li>
                            <li class="menu_item"><a href="#">Сервис</a></li>
                            <li class="menu_item"><a href="#">О Компании</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="header_shopping col-md-3 offset-md-2">
                            <img class="header_shopping_icon" src="img/typcn_shopping-cart.png" alt="">
                            <a class="header_shopping_text">+7 (3452)500-006</a>
                        </div>
                        <a class="phone_icon" href=""><img src="img/phone.png" alt=""></a>
                        <div class="hamburger">
                            <span class="line_1"></span>
                            <span class="line_2"></span>
                            <span class="line_3"></span>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="promo">
            <div class="promo_wrapper">
                <div class="promo_header">МЫ ТАКИЕ КЛАССНЫЕ ПРЯМ не могу</div>
                <div class="promo_subheader">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit ut aliquam, purus sit amet luctus venenatis, lectus </div>
            </div>
            <div class="promo_block">
                <div class="promo_block_item promo_item_1">
                    <div class="title">Продажа</div>
                    <div class="text_block">Профессиональные
                        кофемашины с бесплатной 
                        доставкой по РФ</div>
                </div>
                <div class="promo_block_item promo_item_2">
                    <div class="title">Аренда</div>
                    <div class="text_block">Бесплатная аренда 
                        кофемашины 
                        для ресторана или офиса</div>
                </div>
                <div class="promo_block_item promo_item_4 item_dis_no">
                    <div class="title">Сервис</div>
                        <div class="text_block">Собственный 
                            сервисный цех в городе</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
       </div>
       <div class="carousel">
        <div class="carousel__inner">
            <div><div class="promo_block_item promo_item_3">
                <div class="title">Обучение бариста</div>
                    <div class="text_block">Пройди обучение очно в школе барменов или онлайн</div>
            </div></div>
            <div><div class="promo_block_item promo_item_4 item_dis_yes">
                <div class="title">Сервис</div>
                    <div class="text_block">Собственный 
                        сервисный цех в городе</div>
            </div></div>
            <div><div class="promo_block_item promo_item_5">
                <div class="title">собственный кофе</div>
                    <div class="text_block">Кофе который мы 
                        производим и продаем</div>
            </div></div>
            <div><div class="promo_block_item promo_item_6">
                <div class="title">GRANNYS BAR</div>
                    <div class="text_block">Кофе который мы 
                        производим и продаем</div>
            </div></div>
            <div><div class="promo_block_item promo_item_8">
                <div class="title">Обучение бариста</div>
                    <div class="text_block">Пройди обучение очно в школе барменов или онлайн</div>
            </div></div>
            <div><div class="promo_block_item promo_item_7">
                <div class="title">Бар Ржавый дед</div>
                    <div class="text_block">Пройди обучение очно в школе барменов или онлайн</div>
            </div></div>
          </div>
    </div>
    </header>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-migrate-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/slick.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scr.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: перезагрузки браузера?

Comment: странно у меня ни чего не меняется!

Comment: ну в инструменте разработчика меняю что бы адаптировать!

Comment: там ерунда (надо проверять на реальных устройствах) - надо встроить в страницу для проверки свой скрипт - https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/abpMRoe - вот этот и поставить уже в slick breakpoint эту цифру

Comment: не совсем понял что значит встроить просто подключить файл или прямо в HTML добавить?

Comment: browserSync поставьте

Comment: ну у вас же есть script ? в него добавьте то что с codepen и поместите тег какой то на страницу  и в него выведите размер таким образом .. я же показал пример

Comment: Все вписал! он в теге прописывает я так понимаю экран! мне пишет 992.

Comment: ну вот и поставь первую точку 1024 с одним слайдом (slidesToShow 1) - проверь

Comment: ни чего не меняется!

Comment: что то делаете не так